# how to fix Error No DataBase Provider when Everything is okay

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

When I want to Insert A New Object into the db bellow Error Occured:

**No database provider has been configured for this DbContext**

Services:

```
private IConfiguration config;
public Startup(IConfiguration config) => this.config = config;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(config["ConnectionStrings:MainConnection"]));

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

DataContext:

```
 public class DataContext:DbContext
{
    public DataContext() { }
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Request> Request { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AdminAccept> AdminAccept { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Payment> Payment { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(builder);
    }
}
```

Insert command :

```
public async Task <int> SaveToStorageAsync()
    {

        using (DataContext context=new DataContext())
        {
            context.Request.Add(this);
            return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

however migrations and database created succefully

Comment: Did you check your connection strings? The error seems to say that the database provider in the connection string is not recognized.

Comment: If connection string is wrong why migrations  system is working properly(adding or removing field)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it finally.

everything is okay  but use of **using** expression cause an error.(I wonder why)

to solving it first of all I removed a using and declare a **DataContext** as parameter:

```
    public async Task<int> SaveToStorageAsync(DataContext context)
    {
        context.Request.Add(this);
        return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

after it initiate constructor  in the  main controller :

```
    DataContext context;

    public HomeController(DataContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
```

and finally call function by sending context as a parameter.

hopped you used in your scenarios and good luck

Comment: You also need to pass a DbContextOptions when use `using` method.And the recommend way in asp.net core is dependency Injection the dbcontext.You could check the link in my answer.

Comment: tnx for your answer. please describe more

Comment: The link has explained clearly and you do not need the empty constructor  `public DataContext() { }` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since you register the `DataContext` with the constructor receiving a `DbContextOptions<DataContext> option`.You also need to pass that when you create a DataContext

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext >();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Your connection string");

using (DataContext context = new DataContext (optionsBuilder.Options))
        {
            context.Request.Add(this);
            return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

I suggest that you could use dbContext by DI in controller which is a more recommended way in asp.net core:

```
public class StudentsController : Controller
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public StudentsController(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public async Task <int> SaveToStorageAsync()
    {


        _context.Request.Add(this);
        return await context.SaveChangesAsync();        
    }
}
```

The two ways are included in below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#configuring-dbcontextoptions